# How to set and change ( title of page ) in inertiajs and vue3

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs

I'm using **vue3** and **inertiaJs** with **Laravel8**

I want to change the (**TITLE of page**) if I change the page

I checked in Inertia documentation this code but it doesn't work with me and the title of the page doesn't change
I installed vue-meta

```
  metaInfo() {
     return() {
         title: “Home Page”,
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per v0.4.0 of Inertia, they now bundle their own `inertia-head` component you can use to add meta tags and update the title. There is no longer a need for `vue-meta`.

Simply add the following directly to your page components:

```
<inertia-head>
  <title>Your page title</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Your page description">
</inertia-head>
```

You can find more information in the [change logs of v0.4.0](https://inertiajs.com/releases/inertia-vue3-0.4.0-2021-05-25#new-inertia-head-component).

Comment: For some reason, this is not rendering in the `view-source` of my Laravel 9/Inertia Application, however the title tag works

Comment: @iiiml0sto1 have you manage to solve it?, the title and description is rendering, but the SEO audit tools like "woorank" are not detecting them :(

Comment: @BetoCastillo Unfortunately, I have given up on this for now. It is a private platform of mine and not work-related... but it is, however really annoying that all links shared from my site are just showing as if nothing were present. If you find a nice solution, let me know. it is present if you look in the console. They are just not being caught by pretty much any website or anything

Answer (score 1):

`return()` is a property, not a function. :) So you should do it like this: `return`

```
// parent
metaInfo: {
  meta: [{
    vmid: 'description',
    name: 'description',
    content: 'my standard description',
  }]
}

// child
metaInfo() {
  return {
    meta: [{
      vmid: 'description',
      name: 'description',
      content: this.description,
    }]
  }
},
```

Learn more at [this Vue doc](https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org/guide/special.html#use-child-property-conditionally)

Answer (score 1):

In "inertia-vue3", how do we know that "description" has changed?

```
import { Head } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'

<Head>
  <title>About - My app</title>
  <meta head-key="description" name="description" content="This is a page specific description" />
</Head>
```

In the **view-source**, nothing can be understood !

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


        
        
        <title inertia>test</title>
        

    <body>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This should be its own Question, because right now I face the same issue and cant figure out how to get this to work, nothing is showing in the `view-source`